# Debugging in-page javascript with Chrome when the html is minified?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The scripts on our website are embedded in the html and everything is minified. Throwing a `debugger` statement into the javascript to debug doesn't help very much because there's only actually one line of html in the original source. When the source is prettified with Chrome's code prettifier, the debugger points to the wrong line in the code.

How can I debug minified javascript embedded in the html?

Comment: If it is your website why can't you run the JS through a prettifier, debug it then minimize.

Comment: It should not even need a “prettifier”, since I assume that you _write_ your code in a “normal”, readable way _before_ minifying it anyways, right? So just don’t have it minified until the deployment process, and test with your real sources in your local development stage.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help is that you can set breakpoints in chrome w/o using the `debugger` directive directly in code. Simply view the prettified code output in the chrome sources tab, and then double click on the line where you want to add a breakpoint.